# $\frac{1}{{9\choose r}} -\frac{1}{{10\choose r}} = \frac{11}{6{11\choose r}}$. Is there a way to find $r$ without using algebra?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof

> $$\frac{1}{\dbinom 9r} -\frac{1}{{\dbinom{10}r}} = \frac{11}{6\times \dbinom{11}r}$$

I guess directly applying algebra for this problem would be enough. But are there any simpler and prettier approaches to finding $r$ ?

Comment: I think my first instinct would be to expand $9\choose r$ into $\frac{9!}{r!(9-r)!}$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw It is very simple using algebra if you do that (just solve a quadratic equation in $r!$), but op is searching for an alternative solution.

Comment: You could try every value between $0$ and $9$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use Pascal's rule, or whatever it's called:
$$ \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1} $$
to rewrite the left-hand side as
$$ \frac{\binom{10}{r}-\binom{9}{r}}{\binom{10}{r}\binom{9}{r}} = \frac{\binom{9}{r-1}}{\binom{10}{r}\binom{9}{r}}. $$
Multiplying up gives
$$ \frac{11}{6}\binom{10}{r}\binom{9}{r} = \binom{9}{r-1}\binom{11}{r} $$
Our next trick is another well-known property of binomial coefficients, namely
$$ \binom{n}{k+1}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} $$
Use this to rewrite
$$ \binom{9}{r} = \frac{10-r}{r}\binom{9}{r-1}, $$
so 
$$ \frac{11}{6}\binom{10}{r}\binom{9}{r} = 11\binom{10}{r}\frac{10-r}{r}\binom{9}{r-1} = \binom{9}{r-1}\binom{11}{r} \\
\frac{11}{6}\binom{10}{r}\frac{10-r}{r} = \binom{11}{r} $$
Now we have another binomial identity,
$$ \binom{n+1}{k}=\frac{n+1}{n+1-k}\binom{n}{k}, $$
so
$$ \binom{11}{6r} = \frac{11}{11-r}\binom{10}{r}, $$
reducing the equation to
$$ \frac{1}{11-r} = \frac{10-r}{6r}, $$
which is the quadratic you get normally. This is really not inherently different, but does avoid getting factorials out.

Answer (score 1):

This method is very simple :

$\frac{1}{{9\choose r}} -\frac{1}{{10\choose r}} =\frac{{10\choose r}-{9\choose r}}{{10\choose r}{9\choose r}}=\frac{\frac{{10\choose r}-{9\choose r}}{{9\choose r}}}{{10\choose r}}=\frac{(\frac{{10\choose r}-{9\choose r}}{{9\choose r}})\frac{11*6}{11-r}}{{10\choose r}\frac{11*6}{11-r}}=\frac{11}{6{11\choose r}}\Rightarrow \\
11=(\frac{{10\choose r}-{9\choose r}}{{9\choose r}})\frac{11*6}{11-r}\Rightarrow \\
1=(\frac{{10\choose r}-{9\choose r}}{{9\choose r}})\frac{6}{11-r}\Rightarrow \\
1=(\frac{10}{10-r}-1)\frac{6}{11-r}\Rightarrow \\
1=(\frac{r}{10-r})\frac{6}{11-r}\Rightarrow \\
r^2-21r+110=6r\Rightarrow...$